# Converting an ArrayAdapter to a List<String>

Tags: android, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

I have an array adapter(string), and would like to convert it to a `List<String>`, but after a little googling and a few attempts, I am no closer to figuring out how to do this.

I have tried the following;

```
for(int i = 0; i < adapter./*what?*/; i++){
     //get each item and add it to the list
}
```

but this doesn't work because there appears to be no `adapter.length` or `adapter.size()` method or variable.

I then tried this type of for loop

```
for (String s: adapter){
    //add s to the list
}
```

but adapter can't be used in a foreach loop.

Then I did some googling for a method (in Arrays) that converts from an adapter to a list, but found nothing.

What is the best way to do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++){
     String str = (String)adapter.getItem(i);
}
```

Comment: That looks like exactly what I am looking for, thanks. I hate the fact that google can't make the length names uniform. Would it be too hard for them to have called the method `size()` or `length`?

Comment: Semantically, `getCount()` is more appropriated as it should inform about the number of views that the adapter will create, unlike the `ArrayList` or the array containing the data, which has indeed a size : the number of elements it contains. An `ArrayAdapter` doesn't necessarily contains data, so it has no size.

Comment: Also note that the **ArrayAdapter** class is generic, so if you did `new ArrayAdapter(...)<String>` you can avoid casting the value returned by **getItem()**.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
// Note to the clown who attempted to edit this code.
// this is an input parameter to this code.
ArrayAdapter blammo; 
List<String> kapow = new LinkedList<String>(); // ArrayList if you prefer.

for (int index = 0; index < blammo.getCount(); ++index)
{
    String value = (String)blammo.getItem(index);
    // Option 2: String value = (blammo.getItem(index)).toString();
    kapow.add(value);
}

// kapow is a List<String> that contains each element in the blammo ArrayAdapter.
```

Use option 2 if the elements of the ArrayAdapter are not Strings.